# AngularJS http post not sending object as expected

Tags: json, forms, angularjs, post

I'm trying to post changes to a row in a table via a form in AngularJS. However, it looks like the data selected in the view is not pushed to the object correctly, and I get a 500 error when posting on my real dev environment.

Here's my [code](http://plnkr.co/edit/OfKg0Zh5MTSCgp3cGSm3?p=preview)

**Edit:**

The format I would like to post is: { "id" : "1", "name" : "5k", "distance" : "3.1 miles", "date" : "3/14/2014", "time" : "8 am" }

Comment: elaborate? What is the format you want?

Comment: The format I want when I post is: { "id" : "1", "name" : "5k", "distance" : "3.1 miles", "date" : "3/14/2014", "time" : "8 am" }

Comment: That is nothing like the format of your `editedEvent` content - you need to create a function that will convert the event into that sign up. May I suggest reformatting your input data so that it more accurately matches the format of your output, then you'll have much less confusion.

Comment: I created a convertor, but the editedEvent object doesn't seem to be holding all of the ng-model items in it (i.e. it's missing date, time, and id). So I was only able to convert "name" and "distance", since nothing else was getting passed in through the model. Here's my [updated code](http://plnkr.co/edit/OfKg0Zh5MTSCgp3cGSm3?p=preview)

Comment: This question has been resolved in question [22328452](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22328452/angularjs-missing-ng-model-items-in-scope-object). Thanks for your help Ed.

Comment: No problem, sorry I missed your updated comment.

Answer (score 0):

If I change your save button to run the `save()` method on the scope, then the following is the request payload to `some/url`.

```
{
   "name":{
      "type":"Afternoon",
      "_embedded":{
         "event":{
            "_links":{
               "self":{
                  "href":"www.example.com/events/shift/2"
               }
            },
            "name":"10k",
            "distance":"6.2 miles"
         }
      }
   }
}
```

This is exactly the same data as is in your scope.
As such, I would suggest your server code is doing something wrong with the data..